# How to detect touch on UIImageView inside UIScrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have a UIScrollview in my app and I populate it with LOTS of UIImageViews approx 900. They are all very small and consist of only two different images over and over again.

Now I am having a lot of trouble detecting a touch on one of these UIImageViews.

I have assigned them all a unique TAG so as to be able to distinguish between them but I am really struggling to detect the touch.

The goal is just to be able to change the image of the touched UIImageView.

Due to the large amount of views involved a simple loop checking touch coordinates against each UIImageViews frame is just hanging my app.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Ben

Comment: add a gesture recognizer to the image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to subclass UIScrollView, add touchesBegan etc methods to it.

```
@interface MyScroll : UIScrollView
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the easiest way to do it was adding a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
//Default value for cancelsTouchesInView is YES, which will prevent buttons to be clicked
singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Then use this method to capture the touch:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
  { 
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:myScrollView];
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

UIImageView has touch processing turned off by default. To change that set userInteractionEnabled to YES (see the docs here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also if you want to know which view was hit in a view hierarchy you can use `hitTest:withEvent:` (see docs in UIView) which will be much faster than you looping through the hierarchy.

On a wider note I don't think having 900 UIImageView's on the screen all at once is going to be a good long term strategy. Have you investigated drawing the screen's content via CoreGraphics?

Comment: I do have userInteractionEnabled set to YES. I have changed to trying this `code- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
 
 int i = [[touch view] tag];
 
 NSLog(@"Touched views tag is: %d",i);
 
}` But the problem now is it only detects touches on views that are not a UIScrollView. How could I make it detect the touch in a UIScrollView?? Thanks Ben

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement this method on the UIImageView object:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
      //You clicked inside the object
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event]
}
```

Use the return to tell the application the next touch responder (such as the uiimageview or the scrollview).